# Redemption Shared Folder Problem when moving to Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-2007, outlook-redemption, shared-directory

We currently have an application that works with Outlook 2003. In order to get the owner of a shared contact folder, we simply call:
Redemption.RDOSessionClass.GetFolderFromID() and then took that folder and got the RDOFolder.Store.Name property.

However, when trying this with a shared contact folder in Outlook 2007, the RDOFolder.Store.Name is null.

Everything still works fine for normal contacts and for contacts in "Additional Mailboxes" that I've added to my account.

The approach mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/mstehle/archive/2006/09/07/744798.aspx appears to work, but I would prefer to not release a new version of our application unless I have to.

Basically I want to understand why this is working differently and what I can do, if anything, to fix this from the server end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["There is nothing you can do, this is just how the Exchange provider is
implemented." -Dmitry Streblechenko (MVP)](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba&tid=f3743734-b6e8-4d7e-a1a0-0a9b44aeb1be&cat=en_US_f2349ded-ffa8-474e-a28d-ef611f1d45b4&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited comment : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147715.aspx**

Some thoughts...

Do you have Download Shared Folders (enabled by default in Outlook 2007) turned on in your profile?  My initial guess is that the shared contact folder contents are being cached in your local store and the store name property is no longer valid.

Does it actually return null or throw an exception?

Do you have Outlook Spy?  Invaluable tool for sleuthing this kind of issue, especially if using Redemption.

Have you posted to the [Outlook Programming discussion group](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba&cat=en_US_f2349ded-ffa8-474e-a28d-ef611f1d45b4&lang=en&cr=US)?

Comment: "Use Cached Exchange Mode" is not checked.  I don't know if this matters since the folder was added using the "Open shared contacts" link instead of "Accounts.. Open these mailboxes"

It returns null.

I don't have Outlook Spy.

I've posted it to MSDN forums. I'll post it to your link as well.